# location of partitions in dual-boot installation

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot, windows-7

In my hard drive, the current partitions from left to right are:

Small primary partition for Windows booting (1.17GB), big primary partition C: for Windows system files (116 GB), 115.8 GB unallocated space.

On the unallocated space, I plan to create a big data partition D: for Windows which will be mounted in Ubuntu, and some partitions for installing Ubuntu.

I was wondering which way is better, D: on left of partitions of Ubuntu, or D: on right of partitions of Ubuntu? Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually follow a principle of keeping Windows only partitions  on the left, common partitions in the middle, and Ubuntu only partitions (viz boot, swap, tmp, var, etc) at the extreme right. That means that partitions aren't mixed, and are easy to recover in case of failure. Hence by my reasoning, I would suggest the data partition D: on  the left of Ubuntu.